# After Effects extend script to change image in comp

Tags: extendscript, after-effects

I have tried the below After Effects extend script for being able to select an image folder and import an image in the selected comp. But the script line at `ImportOptions` doesn't work while testing.

```js
function getImage() {
    if (app.project.activeItem instanceof CompItem) {
        var selComp = app.project.activeItem;
        var cname = selComp.name;
        var myTextLayer = selComp.layer("RAAZI").property("Source Text").value;
        var importOptions = new ImportOptions(File(myPath.fsName + '/' + myTextLayer.text + '.png'));
        var newLayer = app.project.importFile(importOptions);
        var insertLayer = selComp.layers.add(newLayer);
        var xpos = insertLayer.property("position").value;          //alert(xpos);

        insertLayer.property("position").setValue(xpos + [-300, 0]);
    } else {
        alert("Please select comp")
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use Code Snippet here? It's not runnable. Please check your question before and after posting

Comment: While posting question, not accepting whole script. So, I have copied only the function where I have stuck. In the importOption, myPath.fsName is mentioned as folder path to locate file. myPath is folder path selected by user using Folder.selectDialog, but not able access this myPath.fsName into my above function written in snippet

Comment: You may need to set the `.file` attribute of the `ImportOptions` rather than first pass it in.  So something like `var importOptions = new ImportOptions().file = new File('/path')`.  See the documentation note here: https://ae-scripting.docsforadobe.dev/other/importoptions